# ALTER TABLE - Got an error writing communication packets

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, pymysql

When I try to perform a query:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN column TEXT NOT NULL
```

The connection stays in an infinite loop (locking the table) and gives this error in the error log:

> [Warning] Aborted connection 1475 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)

So, I tried to increase `max_allowed_packet` as suggested in some topics to 10000M and it performs just one query. The next one (which is soon after) blocks everything again. This is how `my.ini` looks:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.3/data
port=3306
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2033M
max_allowed_packet=10000M
[client]
port=3306
plugin-dir=C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.3/lib/plugin
```

I'm using MariaDB on a Windows environment and I'm trying to perform the query with pymysql (Python):

```
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN column TEXT NOT NULL")
```

Does anyone know a solution for this problematic?

Comment: Just in case : you did not really named you column `column`, right ?

Comment: No, I actually resolved using `commit()` after the query for those interested. It's strange because other queries were committed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The limit for `max_allowed_packet` is only 1G.  Do you get the error when using that value?

[*Reference*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet)

Meanwhile, in

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN column TEXT NOT NULL
```

I hope the table name is not `table` and the column name is not `column`.